# Are questions about cables, connectors, plugs, adapters and powering solutions on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, on-topic

I'd like to ask a serie of questions about power supplies, power solutions and other similar (as mentioned in title). For example:

- How can power microUSB-equipped device directly from car electrical grid?
- Is there any diagram for making own miniUSB to microUSB adapter?

But, I have a feeling that these are more like shopping questions or otherwise off-topic questions here and would like to confirm this before asking to not get all these questions mass-closed.

Comment: Please see: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first example would be off-topic, because it's too broad and also the internet is riddled with advise about car electronics (not as easy as wall adapter power, even though instructables makes you think it is) and 12V (9V~36V+) to 5V generation. So some personal research should give you more than enough to start with and ask specific questions about if something is unclear.

The second is off-topic because of.... pretty much the same reasons.

In basis none of the topics are nescesarily off-topic, but any question requires you to first put in effort, using this website and/or others. Most electronics and electrical subjects have many articles available on reliable sites and if there's stuff unclear, or things you doubt, ***almost*** any question on that is on topic. So long as it is possible to write an answer to it in reasonable time (let's say a rule of thumb of 15 minutes or less) by an experienced hobbyist or professional. Spending more time on it, will then be up to us, if we want to.